# Библиотека libxl не видит файл

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь проверить работоспособность примера библиотеки libxl:

```
#include "libxl.h"
int main()
{
    Book* book = xlCreateBook();
    if (book)
    {
        if (book->load(L"C:\\example.xlsx"))
        {
                cout <<"файл найден" <<endl;
        }  
                else
                {
                 cout <<"файл НЕ найден" <<endl;
                 }
}
```

Но файл example.xlsx, который гарантировано существует не как находится. Не могу понять в чем причина.

Comment: Пробовали `std::cout << book->errorMessage() << '\n';` после неудачного открытия?

Comment: Код доходит до строки book->load и просто переходит на else, как будто бы такого файла по указанному пути нет, но он есть.

Comment: На `else` переходит потому что файл не загрузился, а необязательно потому, что его нет

Comment: А по какой причине может произойти сбой загрузки ?

Comment: А вот для этого-то и стоит вызвать `errorMessage()`

Comment: в консоли вывелось - это :"cant open file for reading"                                                                                                                           и наверное вот это еще в VS:                                                                                      
 "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x7528C41F в ConsoleApplication11.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: libxl::xlerror по адресу памяти 0x0038F958.
Программа "[15956] ConsoleApplication11.exe" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0)."